# VB Remove duplicate lines from textbox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, textbox, duplicates

I am trying to extract the urls from the webpage below in the code.
With this code it works but it give me all the urls a few times.
I only need them once in my textbox.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=test+search")
End Sub

Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
    Dim theElementCollection As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a")
    For Each curElement As HtmlElement In theElementCollection
        If curElement.GetAttribute("href").Contains("/watch") Then
            TextBox1.Text += curElement.GetAttribute("href") & vbCrLf
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [`HashSet(Of String)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) + `String.Join`:

```
Dim uniqueUrls As New HashSet(Of String)

For Each curElement As HtmlElement In theElementCollection
    If curElement.GetAttribute("href").Contains("/watch") Then
        uniqueUrls.Add(curElement.GetAttribute("href"))
    End If
Next

TextBox1.Text = String.Join(vbCrLf, uniqueUrls)
```

Comment: There is only one small problem now. It also takes the advertisement video that is first

Comment: @Mathijs: i don't understand, is this problem new or was it already there with your approach(apart from the duplicates)? How do you detect the advertisement video?